# Why are KML/KMZ parts missing after upload to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz

I have a problem with a KMZ file uploaded to my **[Google Maps places](http://goo.gl/maps/z2UYX)**:

As you can see I have a polygon KMZ file (converted from a shapefile in ArcMap) that has 12 parts but the Google Maps shows only four of them at once (i.e., on three separate views). How can I fix it so they're all visible? Any idea?

The KML is 3,9Mb that's why I made a KMZ that is 0,9Mb.

Answer (score 1):

I employed a trick described [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapstips/alternative-to-paging-on-my-maps) and could get all your polygons in one [page](https://www.google.com/maps?q=https%3a%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fdg%3Dfeature%26ie%3DUTF8%26hl%3Den%26oe%3DUTF8%26vps%3D5%26authuser%3D0%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D207719308852398276835.0004e7aadbef23d9a5c87&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=78.899305,161.71875&t=m&z=7)

Trick is:

> First get the URL of the KML export. When viewing your Custom Map,
>   right click the 'KML' link and copy the link to the clipboard
>   (probably something like 'Copy Shortcut' or 'Copy Link Address' -
>   depends on your browser)
>
> Now display your KML again. I have found it best to open a new Google
>   Maps window, probably just go-to http://maps.google.com and paste in
>   the URL copied earlier INTO the search box, and click the Search Maps
>   button.

Comment: Thank for your help! This KML contains city points also (12 google pins), but they don't appear on the map despite of switched on as u see. How can to visible them? And is this url is emmbed able?